# Создание тестовой БД для тестрирования с помощью junit

Tags: java, mysql, junit

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, разрабатываю веб приложение на java, на этапе тестирования, тест выполняет запись в бд, чтение, тесты на junit, только вот он работает с основной рабочей базой, как сделать так, чтобы тест использовал тестовую БД (MySql)?

Comment: создать отдельную схему?

Comment: а можно ли сделать так, чтобы тест сам создавал копию таблицы без данных, после прохождения теста удалял?

Comment: Запишите скрипт создания базы данных. При запуске тестов иетод анотированный @Before пускай дапит вашу базу. Ждите пока все тесты пройдут, и в конце удалите базу.

Comment: идея понятна, буду признателен, может пример такой реализации имеется?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй для тестирования базы данных фреемверк DBUnit.
http://devcolibri.com/3575